# could finish vs. could have finished

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

*The author died before he could finish his novel.*

*The author died before he could have finished his novel.*

In which sentence is the correct usage of the past tense of the modal verb?

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are correct to my (native Canadian English) eyes. I do perceive a subtle difference in meaning between the two, however: using the perfective "have" strengthens the sense in which the author was not able to finish his novel. That is, I see these two meanings:

*The author died before he could finish his novel*. He was working on his novel, and before he got around to finishing it, he died. Maybe if he worked harder he would have finished it, or maybe it was just impossible.

*The author died before he could have finished his novel*. He was working hard on his novel, but he died so soon that it was impossible for him to finish the novel. Even if he was putting his full effort in, he died before the possibility itself existed.

That is, adding the perfective puts an emphasis on the *impossibility* of finishing the novel, where as without it one leaves unspecified whether, given different circumstances, the author might have been able to finish the novel despite dying so soon.

Comment: +1 Exactly right. *Could* here acts as the past tense of present-tense "real" *can*; *could have* acts as the past tense of present-tense "unreal" *could*.

Comment: Does the second example also imply that the auther could have finished his novel if he hadn't die a sudden death? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB In strict logic, no; but that's a matter of logic, not English. English (as you may have noticed) has little to do with logic.